# How to perform concatenate operation in ms access vba using sql query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have below mentioned table in the ms access called [Info].

```
AB      JDE     Quantity        PO            SMP
IND     AB7049      15      F258738OD       10176
IND     AM7619      21      F258738OD       10176
IND     AS9147      20      F258738OD       10176
ARU     AM7619      8       F118215OG       10176
ARU     AM7619      16      F118215OG       10176
ARU     AM7619      8       F118215OG       10176
ARU     AM7619      12      F258210OD       10176
ARU     AM7619      24      F258210OD       10176
ARU     AM9147      120     F257894OD       10176
ARU     AM9147      102     F257894OD       10176
ARU     AS9147      18      F257905OD       10176
ARU     AS9147      30      F257905OD       10176
```

Here i want perform concatenation and summing operation like below mentioned table.

```
 AB     JDE                     Quantity        PO                                       SMP
IND     AB7049, AM7619, AS9147      56      F258738OD                                   10176
ARU     AM7619, AM9147, AS9147      338     F118215OG, F258210OD, F257894OD, F257905OD  10176
```

here macro needs to concatenate unique JDE and Unique PO and also needs to sum qunatity which are related to JDE and PO. SMP columns is the primary key.

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: I tried use concatenate function but i am getting some error.unfortunately i deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

first SMP doesn't seem to be a primary key.

My approach would be to use a VBA function to get the concenated strings and do the rest in SQL.

VBA function:

```
Public Function getConcValues(ByVal pTablename As String, ByVal pFieldname As String, ByVal pSearchColumn As String, ByVal pSearchValue As String) As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ret As String
    Dim sql As String

    ' prepare SQL
    sql = ""
    sql = sql & "Select distinct [" & pFieldname & "] "
    sql = sql & "  From [" & pTablename & "] "
    sql = sql & " Where [" & pSearchColumn & "] = '" & pSearchValue & "' "
    sql = sql & "Order By [" & pFieldname & "]"

    ' initialize return value
    ret = ""

    ' retrieve unique values based on search criterias
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
    Do Until rs.EOF
        ' add content to return value
        ret = ret & rs.Fields(0) & ", "
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    ' trim last comma if requiered
    If Len(ret) > 0 Then
        ret = Left(ret, Len(ret) - 2)
    End If

    ' cleanup
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    ' return result
    getConcValues = ret
End Function
```

and then you can use it in SQL:

```
SELECT 
    AB, 
    getConcValues("info","JDE","AB",[AB]) AS JDE, 
    Sum(Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity, 
    getConcValues("info","PO","AB",[AB]) AS PO, 
    SMP
FROM info
GROUP BY 
    AB, 
    getConcValues("info","JDE","AB",[AB]), 
    getConcValues("info","PO","AB",[AB]), 
    SMP;
```